# Reading Debugger output in Komodo IDE for Tcl Languare

Tags: tcl, komodo, tclsh, komodo-ide

I am trying to understand errors and exceptions in Tcl. I have written a small code as follows

```
proc Div3 {a b} {
    return [Div2 $a $b]
}

proc Div2 {a b} {
    return [Div $a $b]
}

proc Div {a b} {
   if {$b == 0} {
      error "Error generated by error" "Info String for error" 401
   } else {
      return [expr $a/$b]
   }
}

if {[catch {puts "Result = [Div3 10 0]"} errmsg]} {
   puts "ErrorMsg: $errmsg"
   puts "ErrorCode: $errorCode"
   puts "ErrorInfo:\n$errorInfo\n"
}
```

when I run this using `tclsh.exe`, the debugger output is shown as follows,

```
% tclsh error-file-1.tcl
ErrorMsg: Error generated by error
ErrorCode: 401
ErrorInfo:
Info String for error
    (procedure "Div" line 1)
    invoked from within
"Div $a $b"
    (procedure "Div2" line 2)
    invoked from within
"Div2 $a $b"
    (procedure "Div3" line 2)
    invoked from within
"Div3 10 0"
```

However, when I run the same using `tclsh.exe` via ***Komodo IDE***, I am getting the debugger output as follows

```
ErrorMsg: Error generated by error
ErrorCode: 401
ErrorInfo:
Info String for error
    invoked from within
"DbgNub_uplevelCmd 1 $cmd"
    invoked from within
"Div $a $b"
    invoked from within
"DbgNub_uplevelCmd 1 $cmd"
    invoked from within
"Div2 $a $b"
    invoked from within
"DbgNub_uplevelCmd 1 $cmd"
    invoked from within
"Div3 10 0"
    invoked from within
"DbgNub_uplevelCmd 1 $cmd"
    invoked from within
"DbgNub_Do 0 {1 17 {249 27}} {puts "Result = [DbgNub_Do 1 {1 17 {265 9}} {Div3 10 0}]"}"
```

I can understand the debugger output from `tclsh.exe` but unable to interpret the debugger output from ***Komodo IDE***.

especially, I am unable to understand `DbgNub_Do 0 {1 17 {249 27}} {puts "Result = [DbgNub_Do 1 {1 17 {265 9}} {Div3 10 0}]"}` what are the number shown in the lists (i.e `{1 17 {249 27}}`) and `DbgNub_uplevelCmd 1 $cmd` and `DbgNub_Do`

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know what Komodo is, but its debugger probably replaces the standard `proc` command with its own to add debugging information, so you're seeing a stack trace that includes it. Running through tclsh directly isn't using a debugger, btw.

Comment: @Shawn is there a way to debug using break points from `tclsh.exe`

Comment: Using a debug library? Googling for 'tcl debugger' brings up a few, including this Komodo. I don't think there's a standard one that comes with tcl, unlike some languages.

Answer (score 1):

All the `DbgNub_` commands mentioned in the stack trace are Komodo's extra debugging instrumentation (hiding them in the stack trace is theoretically possible, but messy and the instrumentation *obviously doesn't actually do it*). Generally, you probably ignore those commands as they're not going to be there when you deploy.

If we ignore the `DbgNub_uplevelCmd` bits, we get:

```
Info String for error
    invoked from within
"Div $a $b"
    invoked from within
"Div2 $a $b"
    invoked from within
"Div3 10 0"
    invoked from within
"DbgNub_Do 0 {1 17 {249 27}} {puts "Result = [DbgNub_Do 1 {1 17 {265 9}} {Div3 10 0}]"}"
```

That's recognisably similar to the standard trace except for the lack of line number information (and the `DbgNub_Do`, which is obviously instrumenting the code inside the `catch` directly).

---

Generally, Tcl's result status consists of:

1. A result **code**. This is `TCL_OK` (= 0) on success of a piece of code, `TCL_ERROR` (= 1) if an exception was thrown, and a few other values for other things (`TCL_RETURN`, `TCL_BREAK` and `TCL_CONTINUE`). Those names are defined at the C level.
2. A result **value** that is stored in the interpreter. In ancient versions of Tcl this was a simple string, but it's been a reference-counted typed value for over 20 years. (Tcl does have a type system. It's just very different from every other language's in that strings are the supertype of all other types.)
3. A result **dictionary** that contains additional information. Standard entries (it's possible to define your own too) in this are:

   1. The error information, a.k.a stack trace that gets written to the `errorInfo` global to support old code. Only really meaningful for errors.
   2. The error code, a machine readable exception descriptor that gets written to the `errorCode` global to support old code. Again, only really meaningful for errors.
   3. The error line. The bit that's used to generate the number in the message `(procedure "Div" line 1)` and so on.
   4. The level, which is used by `return` to do multi-level returns.

There's some other bits and pieces that only kick in in a few cases (such as when a `try`'s `finally` clause throws an exception when the body of the exception threw, a gnarly case in lots of languages).

Comment: As for what the `DbgNub_` commands are doing, it's simply not publicly documented. Debugging tools in general poke around things at a fairly low level.